# Setting my crontab did not work. I must have set it in the wrong place. Where is the correct spot to set it?

Tags: apache, cron

The other day I edited my crontab file, but the old settings are still being run.

I am working with Apache. So I went to

```
/etc/crontab
```

and I saved it. But the old crontab is still running.  Is this not the place to edit the crontab? Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

This is my grep cron:

```
[root]# ps aux | grep cron
root      1396  0.0  0.4   3000   704 pts/0    S+   21:12   0:00 grep cron
root      8114  0.0  0.5   4412   968 ?        Ss    2011   0:02 crond
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a question for some other board, but the answer is that you don't edit cron files directly, you use the tool "crontab" as an executable. run man crontab, or Google crontab.

```
EDITOR=emacs (or vim or whatever) to set you editor first.

crontab -e
```

to edit

```
crontab -l
```

to list current cron tasks

Comment: I edited the file by ftp-ing to it. Should I only edit it in something like vi? Is that what you meant?

Comment: See my edited version of my answer. You ssh to the machine and run crontab as an executable. (or use some GUI front-end tool)

Comment: yeah I did that, and the new setting comes up. But still the old one runs.

Comment: I did vi crontab in /etc and the new setting is showing up...very confusing.

Comment: perhaps you have multiple cron processes running now? Try something like ps aux | grep cron or reboot the machine if that won't cause problems

Comment: I just posted the result of my grep cron in my original question.

Comment: [root@ etc]# crontab -l gives result:
no crontab for root

Comment: were you setting it on root or another user? You can ask for user "foo" with crontab -l -u foo

Comment: I am not sure who I was setting it for to be honest. But I am always logged in as root.  But I guess the system thinks otherwise :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21888/discussion-between-genadinik-and-devin-ceartas)